# Buildroot problem "modprobe: can't change directory to '4.4.34+'"

Tags: wifi, qemu, buildroot

I am trying to build a working embedded system for Raspberry Pi Zero W with Buildroot. I'm testing it in QEMU for now. The system boots OK from sdcard.img, but the wifi drivers will not load. I am loading the wifi kernel module in an init script `/etc/init.d/S39wifidrivers`:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Load Wifi driver
printf "Loading Wifi Driver: "
/sbin/modprobe brcmfmac
[ $? = 0 ] && echo "OK" || echo "FAIL"
```

But on boot I get the error message:

```
modprobe: can't change directory to '4.4.34+'. No such file or directory
```

If I recompile using mdev instead of the above script, I get the same error. I'm also getting two other boot errors that might be related -

```
Starting network: Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant 
n180211: 'n180211' generic netlink not found
Failed to initialize driver 'n180211'
wlan0: Unsupported driver 'n180211'
```

And,

```
/bin/sh: can't access tty; job control turned off
```

Which prevents me from logging in to the getty. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated, as I'm pretty far out of my depth here!

Here's my defconfig:

```
BR2_arm=y
BR2_arm1176jzf_s=y
BR2_CCACHE=y
BR2_KERNEL_HEADERS_4_4=y
BR2_TOOLCHAIN_BUILDROOT_CXX=y
BR2_ROOTFS_DEVICE_CREATION_DYNAMIC_MDEV=y
BR2_ROOTFS_USERS_TABLES="../br-external/board/users.config"
BR2_ROOTFS_OVERLAY="../br-external/board/rootfs_overlay"
BR2_ROOTFS_POST_BUILD_SCRIPT="board/raspberrypi0w/post-build.sh"
BR2_ROOTFS_POST_IMAGE_SCRIPT="board/raspberrypi0w/post-image.sh"
BR2_ROOTFS_POST_SCRIPT_ARGS="--add-pi3-miniuart-bt-overlay"
BR2_LINUX_KERNEL=y
BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_CUSTOM_TARBALL=y
BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_CUSTOM_TARBALL_LOCATION="$(call github,raspberrypi,linux,83b36f98e1a48d143f0b466fcf9f8c4e382c9a1c)/linux-83b36f98e1a48d143f0b466fcf9f8c4e382c9a1c.tar.gz"
BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_DEFCONFIG="bcmrpi"
BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_DTS_SUPPORT=y
BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_INTREE_DTS_NAME="bcm2708-rpi-0-w"
BR2_PACKAGE_RPI_FIRMWARE=y
BR2_PACKAGE_RPI_WIFI_FIRMWARE=y
BR2_PACKAGE_DNSMASQ=y
BR2_PACKAGE_OPENSSH=y
BR2_PACKAGE_WPA_SUPPLICANT=y
BR2_PACKAGE_WPA_SUPPLICANT_AP_SUPPORT=y
BR2_TARGET_ROOTFS_EXT2=y
BR2_TARGET_ROOTFS_EXT2_4=y
BR2_TARGET_ROOTFS_EXT2_SIZE="80M"
# BR2_TARGET_ROOTFS_TAR is not set
BR2_PACKAGE_HOST_DOSFSTOOLS=y
BR2_PACKAGE_HOST_GENIMAGE=y
BR2_PACKAGE_HOST_MTOOLS=y
```

And my `../br-external/board/rootfs_overlay/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
  pre-up wpa_supplicant -D nl80211 -i wlan0 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf -B
  post-down killall -q wpa_supplicant
```

And my `../br-external/board/users.config`:

```
jez -1 jezgroup -1 =passwd /home/jez /bin/sh tty Comment
```

The output of `ls output/target/lib/modules/`:

```
4.14.95
```

I tried changing that to 4.4.34+ just to see what would happen and the modprobe error went away, but it was followed by other errors complaining about the same thing.

Thanks in advance!!!!!!

Comment: QEMU is out of scope here. Have you tried to run it on the Raspberry Pi Zero W?

Answer (score 1):

In retrospect, this was a dumb question - trying to run an embedded Raspberry Pi OS on QEMU *is not supported*. Those who run Raspbian on QEMU use a custom kernel specifically designed for QEMU.

The reason I was doing this is because the serial and HDMI adapters I ordered for my Pi are still in the mail (any month now).

There's a silver lining - I just flashed the SD and put it in my Pi0w and the **wifi access point actually appeared**. So I've gone straight to a wifi access point with a SSH login with no serial or HDMI debugging - how's that for dumb luck.